# Using .NET dll on PHP

Tags: php, .net, com

I'm trying out how to use my .net coded dll functions on php. I have been trying and researching for hours, still couldn't get it working. PHP version is 5.4.4

**Error message:** 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `php4winbook.examples': Invalid syntax ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testdll\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testdll\index.php(13): com->com('php4winbook.exa...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testdll\index.php on line 13

**What I've tried:**

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27291
http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/04/24/how-to-use-.net-assemblies-in-php.aspx

Best resources I found so far...

**My codes:**

```
<?php
$test = new COM("php4winbook.examples");
$hellmes = $test->showname("Andrew");
echo $hellmes;
?>
```

.net dll codes, just a simple hello world. "Make assembly COM-Visible" options checked and signed with a key.

[image: codes] 

**Adding into assembly:**
[image]

However I couldn't find examples inside C:/windows/assembly folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your DLLs in windows before using it in COM class.